# Print Image Based on Pre-Defined Variable

Tags: php, image, e-commerce

I'm pretty new with PHP and I was wondering how to code something like this, Sorry I couldn't figure out search terms on how i might end up finding related answers

Specifically this would be checking to see if a shopping cart was empty by using the total

```
if PHP $var = 0
then $printsrc='http://localhost/images/image1.jpg'
elseif $var > 0
then $printsrc='http://localhost/images/image2.jpg'
```

then to change the image within an image tag like

```
<img src="<php $printsrc ?>" id="hello">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it like this-->

```
<img src="<php $printsrc ?>" id="hello">
```

TO

```
<img src="<?php echo $printsrc ?>" id="hello">
```